Android (and maybe other phones) game - side scrolling, primary attack being punching, limited ability to control, fighting monsters
At least 5-6 years ago, I had a game on my Android phone, maybe through an Amazon service that offered me frequent free and discounted games. It had colorful cartoonish artwork, and a frenetic pace where the character would constantly move to the right of the level with the only controls, as I remember it, being to jump or to punch. You jumped to avoid obstacles and you punched monsters, and your goal was to make it to the end of the level. Providing some variety, you could use your accrued points to buy power-ups, which I think consisted of abilities and masks, which you were limited as to how many you could have equipped. I think some of the power-ups gave you additional moves that you could do with the combination of the two buttons. As with many games at the time, I think there were daily rewards, rewards for checking in consistently, and rewards for accomplishing certain goals, like killing 50 enemies total, completing 2 stages without taking any damage, things like that. I want to say that there were some "goal of the day" goals and others that kind of accrued until you completed them, or maybe spent some of your currency to remove and replace with a new one.
I don't think that it was a game I got via a Humble Bundle. It might also be much older... I have a vague memory of playing a stage while I was at CCAC with my wife, and she got a degree with them before we got married, over eleven years ago. But I also remember playing it during a rehearsal with a Shakespeare group I was with, which I stopped performing with about five years ago. I definitely remember it as fighting monsters, maybe mythological ones, with magic being an aspect of the power-ups, but I only have a vague memory that the monsters might have been drawn from some combination of Greek mythology and D&D creatures, things like dire wolves, snakes, and chimeras.

Game is possibly Punch Quest. You control the character who can only jump or punch, can't stop. Go as far as you can, pick power-ups on the way (thunder fist ftw).



I personally got it from Humble Bundle.

Huh. So it was a Humble Bundle.  Unfortunately, it looks like one of those games that aged out of the operating system updates. I think I kept discounting it because I saw Punch Club first.

https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidGaming/comments/c7ozol/what_happened_to_punch_quest_on_google_play/ for some discussion on it having become obsolete.
